# Security measures between appmaker and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: security, google-app-maker

The communication between the browser and the appmaker runtime environment is secured by HTTPS.  What security measures are put in place to secure the connection between appmaker runtime on Google and the Google cloud database?

In Appmaker it simply asks for the database address and credentials when setting up a Google Cloud SQL connection.  There is no option about security.  I assume it's secure as both the appmaker and the database live in Google Cloud.  Can someone confirm the right security measures is in place?